# how to call two or more web methods Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{

    $("#Result").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxJquery.aspx/GetDate",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i have one more method as GetName, how to code it to call two or more methods like above

Comment: you can not call more than one url in one ajax call

Comment: Call two requests at same time?

Comment: Copy the `$.ajax` method and add another below this one?

Answer (score 2):

Call the second one in `success` function, instead of `alert(msg.d);`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AjaxJquery.aspx/GetDate",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AjaxJquery.aspx/GetDate1",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);

                    }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, you may accept an answer then.

Comment: Hi David, above same manner i wanna display data in asp.net Gridview,. tell me the solution

Comment: 1) It's a separate question from another field. Post with relevant tags and you may get an answer from those who work with .NET 2) I don't take orders, especially from total strangers.